# How to get all the changes of a Pull Request when triggering on pull_request_review?

Tags: github-actions

I currently have a GitHub Action that triggers on:

```
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
```

I then want to run a command, which expects the contents of changes of the Pull Request.

Previously, I was using

```
on: 
  push
```

and I had no issues with the contents of the files being available in the Action context.

However, my command is failing now, and I think it's because the context only includes the commit that the action was triggered on (no file changes.)
Previously I was running this action on `push` and that was always successful, with the file changes being available in the context.

I'm using:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

(https://github.com/actions/checkout)

Is it possible to use this to have all the file changes on the Pull Request within the Action context?

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that by using an open source Action available on marketplace:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # windows-latest | macos-latest
    name: Test changed-files
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # OR "2" -> To retrieve the preceding commit.

      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v14.6

      - name: List all changed files
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
            echo "$file was changed"
          done
```

The solution above uses git checkout and git diff to get files changed by PR. Alternatively if you really need just information about paths changed and you don't really need files themselves (no checkout) - you can do it without checkout using `gh` CLI:

```
gh pr view XXX --json files -q '.files[].path'
```

You can run it like this:

```
jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: gh pr view XXX --json files -q '.files[].path'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the purpose of using both the `fetch-depth` setting, and the `tj-actions` project?

Comment: Fetch-depth is required to get full history of GIT repository - not required for all actions, but `tj-actions/changed-files` requires a checkout before you can use it - it operates on local git repository, not on remote repo.

Comment: Got it - should I be able to use `fetch-depth` without tj-actions/changed-files to get all the changes within the Action context?

Comment: To clarify, I don't need to output a list of the changed files.  I just need to run a command as part of the Action that runs on the changes.

Comment: Adding only `fetch-depth: 0` still causing the same issue, which is strange because from my understanding, this should fetch the history of the branch.  I'm wondering if it cannot be used with the pull_request_review trigger?

Comment: You have to get all changed files first, then you can pass it to your command that you need to run. 
If your command requires access to the files themselves - you have to checkout repo first.
If you just need list of changed files, I added alternative method

Comment: Thanks! I think I should be able to just use `checkout` as I want access to the files themselves - basically my Action takes all the contents of the files, and creates a new file with the combined content.  This was previously working when I was triggering on `push` it's only when I've changed by Action to trigger on `pull_request_review` that it's no longer working.  And I was previously using `checkout`

Comment: You have to use checkout if you need access to the files. Combine `changed-files` with `checkout` and you can easily get what you need.